# No hdmi signal?

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi, dvi

Basically i was using a DVI output cable connected directly to my graphics card. I looked up "Intel graphics" and when i tried to open it my screen went black. I shut down my computer (manually) and turned it on again only for the screen to not even notice. I switched to an HDMI output and this time the screen DID turn on just to display a blue screen with the words "hdmi no signal"....

I'm not quite sure what happened? I removed the DVI cable and tried only HDMI and still the same "hdmi no signal", and then when I try to use the DVI output cable the monitor doesn't even recognize that i even turned on the computer at all.

Not quite sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

Okay... so for the sake of anyone else who might have this problem I'm going to answer my own question and how I solved it. **Make sure you have the network adapter for your motherboard (you can probably download it online). You will need it later to update your other drivers online, this is ASSUMING you're installing windows because I have no idea if other OS's allows you to install your drivers automatically by searching online** This is assuming you have **nothing** is display to your monitor. Basically what you have to do is remove your hard drives/SSD's and graphics cards. It should boot to BIOS now. Make sure you have a bootable OS and set the boot priorities in your BIOS to whatever method you're going to use to boot to your OS (which ever it is). Now connect your drivers back to your pc and restart your computer (make sure your live cd/usb is in the computer so you can boot it). It should boot to your OS install screen. There should be an option to format\delete everything on your hard drives, go ahead and do that. **On the windows install you can probably move some files on your hard drives to another drive if you don't want to delete everything (ex: some family pictures) but for my case I didn't do that because i really didn't have anything important nor did i want to go through the hassle since i didn't have much in the first place**. Now after that do the clean install to your main drive (mine was an SSD I had). Install your network adapter and update your drivers and everything should be working. Now put your graphics card back in and update the drivers for that too. Everything should be working now. **I would only try this only if you're all out of other options**